# Bench Pressing vs. Push-ups

Tags: weightlifting, exercise-technique, push-ups, bench-press

Does bench pressing work out the same muscles as push-ups?

If not, What's the difference?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Bench press**

- Can use a lot more weight, so it's ideal for the low rep anaerobic range. It's for mass building.
- Can be assisted by a spotter, so you can go to failure. This is good for breaking plateaus and stimulating growth.
- More dangerous if you don't have a spotter. The bar can fall on your chest if you have no more strength to get it back up.
- You can do incline, decline, or flat bench press which targets upper, lower, and entire chest respectively. A push up is the same angle as a flat bench press.

**Push up**

- Only uses 50-70% of the body weight depending on your body proportions, so you're going to do higher rep aerobic range. It's for cardiovascular conditioning.
- Wrists have to do a little bit more work because of the bent position.
- Allows for hand position variations than bench press. For example, placing hands near the abs turn the pushup into a tricep workout. Another example is the diamond pushup, which puts more emphasis on inner chest and tricep.

Comment: Don't forget about incline and decline pushups to target different muscles. Really the only main difference between pushups and bench press is the amount of weight.

Comment: Both can be used aerobically or anaerobically depending on variables such as load, sets and rest intervals.  One nice thing is that you can do push ups anywhere!

Comment: Since I usually work out alone, I do my bench presses using a squat rack. I set the pins so that the weight stops just above my chest and I can safely do the exercise to failure without a spotter. Just make sure that you set the pegs high enough that the weight doesn't rest on your chest at all. Depending on the adjustability of the rack and the bench that you're using, it might not be possible to find a good height, so this can be hit or miss. I've been lucky at most of my gyms in the past.

Comment: The squat rack doesn't work the stablizer muscles

Comment: Bench pressing with dumbbells is another option if you don't have a spotter as at failure you can drop them to your sides.

Comment: @jojo - It sounded to me that Aardvark was referring to using the safety bars in a conventional squat rack or power rack, not a Smith machine. A setup of that sort *does* work the stabilizer muscles because it's still a bench press with a free barbell instead of a machine press. (If I'm wrong and he's using a Smith Machine or similar and calling it a squat rack, then your response is totally accurate and appropriate.)

Answer (score 18):

I'm sorry, but the selected answer for this question is terribly ill-informed. It doesn't even answer the OP's question of which muscles are actually utilized for each of these activities.

*Common myth #1:* The pushup is merely an exercise for muscular endurance.

*Common myth #2:* The bench press is far superior to the pushup for building muscle, mainly due to the ability to quickly and easily adjust resistance.

The problem with the bench press is the bench itself. Your upper body is rendered immobile by the bench, preventing your core from doing any work to stabilize your body; it's all done for you, which is a bad thing. Many professional bodybuilders agree that if you don't have core strength, you have no strength at all. The pushup demands core strength, while the bench press ignores it.

The bench press also ignores the serratus anterior (muscle group on sides of chest from 1st to 8th ribs,) while the pushup, again, demands it.

In fact, doing a proper pushup engages every muscle between your shoulders and toes. Including abdominal, hip, thighs, etc. The bench press can certainly chisel your chest, but little else. You are conserving energy by using far less muscle groups, but you are chiseling far less of your body. So you will end up looking disproportioned if the bench is all you care about.

There are also risks involved with the bench press that are moot with pushups. The bench press will put increased strain on ligaments and tendons (not good,) and can even damage the cartilage pads between your joints (very bad.)

Let's also stomp the misconception in this thread about not being able to apply additional resistance to a pushup. This can easily be accomplished through stacking plates on one's back, wearing a weighted vest, wrapping chains around the torso, elevating one's feet, using one arm, well you get the idea.

*Quick anecdote:* I know a guy who was doing 350+ on the press, but tore a rotator cuff whilst throwing a tennis ball to his dog. Why? Because all he cared about was the bench. He believed he was far stronger than he actually was simply because of the size of his arms and chest.

`*EDIT*`

> Sources:
>
> http://www.livestrong.com/article/139168-push-ups-vs-bench-press/
>   http://thebodyweightfiles.blogspot.com/2008/02/pushup-vs-bench-press.html

Comment: Could you please add some sources for your theses?

Comment: I think a well rounded workout with squats, deadlifts, overhead pressing, benching, chins and dips will build a strong well proportioned body.  Pushups are just not easily incrementally loadable.

Comment: @mchlfchr Sure thing, I've edited my answer and added sources to the bottom. Thanks for pointing that out :)

Comment: Agreed. The selected answer for this question doesn't remotely answer the question, this should be selected as answer instead.

Comment: All of the features of your enhanced/better answer focus on more muscles throughout the body being used or engaged.  If the exerciser is trying to isolate and develop the pectoral muscles, that makes your explanation much worse. not better.  Not engaging the core is only a bad thing if you don't do anything else.  I get that you prefer the pushup, but that doesn't make it better, or worse.  It all depends on the entirety of the workout program and the goals of the person exercising.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet My answer has nothing to do with personal preference. OP asked a very direct question about which muscles are engaged in the press vs the pushup.

Comment: No, your answer clearly advocates one as superior to the other. Don't pretend that referring to the bench press as, fundamentally, having a "problem" is isn't making a subjective assessment, overall. You're also creating straw man arguments in the form of the "myths" that no one else brought up, just so you can address which is "superior."  That's entirely about personal preference, and that has nothing to do with merely answering which muscles are engaged between one vs the other.  -1, now, for this phony and dishonest response.